# Sign a lot of messages with same private key

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature

I'm creating platform where I need to sign a lot of messages (1k/sec), I want to use Ed25519 signature, because it has the best performance. Is it safe to sign that many messages with the same private key? Or it will have no impact in revealing private key?

Comment: Should be fine. I don't believe there's any limit on the number of signatures you can do with an ECDSA key, but I'll let the experts at crypto.se give a definitive answer.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth: for standard _ECDSA_ (X9.62/FIPS186 not RFC6979) doing more than roughly sqrt(groupsize) would have unacceptable risk of repeating the random k, which is catastrophic. But EdDSA including Ed25519 uses synthetic nonce which avoids this issue. FWIW I don't see any bounds in those of DJB's papers I've looked at, or RFC8032.

Comment: Be warned that there have been practical *side channel attacks* against EdDSA. I found "Practical fault attack against the Ed25519 and EdDSA signature schemes" but more importantly "Breaking Ed25519 in WolfSSL" which just relies on power analysis / EM leakage.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely safe to sign any number of messages with an Ed25519 private key. The only non-deterministic input is the hash of the message to be signed and the hash of the private key itself. The number of signatures that would need to be obtained in order to reveal the private key is likely to be so high that an attacker would be better off attempting to crack the key directly.

Comment: That last sentence needs some explaining. Is "likely so high" doesn't inspire much confidence and the method on how the private key can (or cannot) be revealed is missing.

Comment: I would expect something about the size of the hash over the private key `h` and the generation of `r` in the answer.